# Visual studio Datagridview Does not update,insert or delete

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I'm using Datatable to populate datagridview in my windows form application which uses sql server database. But when I edit the datagridview no change appears to database. 
I Opened the datagridview's datatable in design mode and selected the generate insert update and delete statement. but when I press ok and reopen this window this item is still unchecked.

[image]

Comment: i guess you know that you have to call SqlDataAdapter.Update to update your edited values to the sql server?

Comment: I use DataTable as BindingSource for DGV..  but google ..

Comment: http://vb.net-informations.com/datagridview/vb.net_datagridview_database.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379615/datagridview-save-changes-to-database-vb-net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404787/how-to-save-changes-from-datagridview-to-the-database

Comment: @prfctbydsgn My problem is that my data adapter does not have update method.