# Changes in Datagridview not saving in table SQLite vb.net

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, datagridview

I'm trying to save changes made to datagridview into the table tbl_invent, the changes i make commits to datagridview but it does not save to the table (database), also it doesn't have any error, all i received is a message saying "Records Updated = 0". anyone could point me to the right direction?

```
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from tbl_Invent", connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    'Dim cmdbuilder As New SQLite.SQLiteCommandBuilder(da)

    Dim i As Integer
    da.TableMappings.Add("tbl_Invent", "tbl_Invent") 'add due to error unable to Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'
    Try
        i = da.Update(ds, "tbl_Invent")
        MsgBox("Records Updated= " & i)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    connection.Close()
```

i already check out this thread:
[How to save changes from DataGridView to the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404787/how-to-save-changes-from-datagridview-to-the-database)

-and-

[Datagridview save changes to Database vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379615/datagridview-save-changes-to-database-vb-net)

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: According to that code, you are creating a new, i.e. EMPTY, `DataSet` and then trying to save the changes that it contains back to your database.  If the `DataSet` contains nothing at all then obviously it contains no changes so there's nothing to save.  You need to create a `DataTable` first and bind it to the grid, then make the changes in the grid, then pass that `DataTable` to your `Update` call.

Comment: i added  dim dt as new datatable, da.Fill(dt),  DataGridView1.DataSource = dt then change da.update(ds,"dt"). still no save. i think im i made an error in the da.update...or what i did is all wrong?

Comment: @jmcilhinney after reading your answer in vbforums (well i assume it's you same name) i also added Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables("tbl_Invent"), still nothing is saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be obvious that you're not going to save any changes if you don't make any changes between creating/populating your `DataTable` and trying to save the changes.  You need to create the `DataTable`, populate it and bind it in one method (probably the `Load` event handler of the form), then the user makes the changes, then you save the changes from the same `DataTable` in another method (probably the `Click` event handler of a `Button`.  E.g.

```
Private table As New DataTable
Private adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SQL query here", "connection string here")
Private builder As New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    adapter.Fill(table)
    BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BindingSource1.EndEdit()
    adapter.Update(table)
End Sub
```

The `DataTable` is created when the form is, the user makes the changes in the grid and clicks the `Button` and then you save the changes from THE SAME `DataTable`, not a new one that you just created that contains no changes.

Comment: Thank you for that. i'm very rusting coding in VB, right now i'm trying to re-learn everything(i stop coding vb 6 was still the new). quick question though i have 5 datagridview in the same form(1 in each tab), i'm guessing i will create a datatable for each, can it be put on tabpage_enter() event? or it must be on the onload event?